# Positioning 3 content boxes next to each other

Tags: html, css

I have a main container called content, within that container I have 3 divs. Now I want them to be aligned next to each other like so: X X X. In a tutorial I read that I should float them all to the left. This works for the first 2 but the third one never appears. I'm sure the path is correct, because when I put it as second it does show up. Can somebody help me?

**HTML**

```
<div id="content"
    <div id="about_us"></div>
    <div id="our_services"></div>
    <div id="contact_us"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content {
width: 1200px;
height: 254px;
}

#about_us {
background-image: url(../website/images/about_benshore.png);
width: 307px;
height: 183px;
float: left;
margin-top: 26px;
margin-left: 119px;
}

#our_services {
background-image: url(../website/images/our_services.png);
width: 308px;
height: 184px;
float: left;
margin-top: 26px;
margin-left: 23px;
}

#contact_us {
background-image: url(../website/images/contact_us.png);
width: 307px;
height: 183px;
float: left;
margin-top: 26px;
margin-left: 23px;
}
```

Comment: <div id="content"> <!-- BEGIN CONTENT -->
 
 <div id="about_us"> <!-- BEGIN ABOUT US -->
 </div> <!-- END ABOUT US -->
 
 <div id="our_services"> <!-- BEGIN OUR SERVICES -->
 </div> <!-- END OUR SERVICES -->
 
 <div id="contact_us"> <!-- BEGIN CONTACT US -->
 </div> <!-- END CONTACT US -->
 
 </div> <!-- END CONTENT -->

Comment: Appears to be working to me: http://jsfiddle.net/vARCR/1/

Comment: Yeah, I see it in the jsfiddle, strangely it doesn't work on my browsers.

Comment: Stupid of me to not fiddle around with it before asking a question. When I float the 3rd box to the right it works.. Sorry for wasting the time of you guys. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding overflow:auto to #content.

Also make sure that the width of your elements plus their respective margins dont add up to more than the width of #content.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Width doesn't exceed the width of #content, and overflow: auto doesn't do anything.

Comment: Stupid of me to not fiddle around with it before asking a question. When I float the 3rd box to the right it works.. Sorry for wasting the time of you guys. Thanks anyway!